# javasisst - Not compiling due to "missing" field

Tags: java, maven, javassist

I have the following code:

```
CtClass player = ClassPool.getDefault().get("org.spongepowered.api.entity.living.player.Player");
CtField toAdd = CtField.make("public java.lang.String nick = null;", player);
player.addField(toAdd);
```

and later I have this:

```
e.getTargetEntity()/*this function returns a class that implements Player*/
Player.nick = e.getTargetEntity().getName();
```

How can I make this code compile? Both eclipse and maven throw compile exceptions because obviously, they don't know about the fact that Player.nick is a field. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use reflection to set the field.

```
package hello;

import com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream;
import javassist.ClassPool;
import javassist.CtClass;
import javassist.CtField;

class Player {
}

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        CtClass player = ClassPool.getDefault().get("hello.Player");
        CtField toAdd = CtField.make("public java.lang.String nick = null;", player);
        player.addField(toAdd);

        Class patchedPlayer = player.toClass();
        Object o = patchedPlayer.newInstance();

        patchedPlayer.getField("nick").set(o, "hello, Player");

        String s = new XStream().toXML(o);
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

will print

```
<hello.Player>
  <nick>hello, Player</nick>
</hello.Player>
```

Also make sure `e.getTargetEntity()` returns object of patched class, not original one.